Auth.js Error: UntrustedHost with Google Sign-In despite SSL and setting trueHost to true
I’m working on a project where users can authenticate using Google Sign-In via Auth.js. However, I keep getting the following error:
[auth][error] UntrustedHost: Host must be trusted. URL was: https://www.dealdhoondo.com/api/auth/signin/google?. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#untrustedhost

I have already tried the following steps:
1.  Added my auth_url correctly in the configuration.
2.  Set trueHost to true in my configuration.
3.  My domain (https://www.dealdhoondo.com) has an SSL certificate, so it’s accessible via HTTPS.

Configuration snippet:
export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  adapter: PostgresAdapter(pool),
  providers: [Google],
  trustHost: true,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login',
  }
})

In my docker:
ENV AUTH_URL=https://www.dealdhoondo.com/

As well tried
ENV AUTH_URL=https://www.dealdhoondo.com/api/auth

What I’ve tried so far:
•   Checked that my domain has a valid SSL certificate.
•   Ensured the AUTH_URL is correct and matches the domain.
•   Set trueHost to true.

Still encountering the issue:
Despite the above, I continue to get the UntrustedHost error.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Logs:
k logs pod/fmd-ui-9f999d666-svkg5
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.11
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Network:      http://0.0.0.0:3000

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 121ms
[auth][error] UntrustedHost: Host must be trusted. URL was: https://www.dealdhoondo.com/api/auth/signin/google?. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#untrustedhost


have you got workaround ?
